# Chinese characters of Ba Gua

Tags: tikz-pgf, xecjk

This question maybe for Chinese, but I'm trying to write something with Latex (actually XeTex), so I ask here.

I'm basically trying to draw the Ba Gua sign with TikZ and I'm almost done with it. I'm only missing the Chinese characters to go with it. Can anyone help telling me what I should put in the right places?

At the end it should look like this:

[image: Ba Gua sign]

My MWE is (I left some of the lengths I need later for the trigrams and some comments that don't make sense here: they are not really needed in this MWE):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{KaiTi}

%Lengths definition
\newlength{\radiustai} %Radius of Taijitu symbol
\setlength{\radiustai}{1cm}
\newlength{\thickness} %Thickness of the trigram lines
\setlength{\thickness}{0.3\radiustai} %Change this factor to make the lines thicker or thinner
\newlength{\iradiusbagua} %Distance from center of Taijitu to the first line of Ba Gua.
\setlength{\iradiusbagua}{1.4\radiustai} %Change the factor to make the Ba Gua bigger or smaller. Factor 1 would make it tangent to the Taijitu.
\newlength{\smallradius} %Offset from the center for the trigram lines (see below for computation)
\newlength{\basedistance} %Base distance from lowest corner of Ba Gua trigram

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} %It's not necessary here, but I use it anyway

%Colours definition
\definecolor{triborder}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{trifill}{gray}{0}
\definecolor{octafill}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{bckearth}{RGB}{240,230,140}
\definecolor{bckwater}{RGB}{30,144,255}
\definecolor{bckfire}{RGB}{220,20,60}
\definecolor{bckwood}{RGB}{50,205,50}
\definecolor{bckmetal}{RGB}{192,192,192}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  %External octagon: thanks to Mark Wibrow for the idea (from an answer on stackexchange).
  \draw[line width=1,fill=octafill] (22.5:\iradiusbagua+8.5\thickness) \foreach \i in {45,90,...,315}{-- (\i+22.5:\iradiusbagua+8.5\thickness)} -- cycle;
  \draw[line width=2,fill=white] (22.5:\iradiusbagua+6.5\thickness) \foreach \i in {45,90,...,315}{-- (\i+22.5:\iradiusbagua+6.5\thickness)} -- cycle;
  \foreach \i in {22.5,67.5,...,337.5}{\draw[line width=1] (\i:\iradiusbagua+6.5\thickness) -- (\i:\iradiusbagua+8.5\thickness);}
  \foreach \i [count=\xi from 1] in {?\ k\={u}n\ ?,?\ lì\ ?,?\ xùn\ ?,?\ zhèn\ ?} {\node[rotate=45*(\xi-2)] at (45*\xi:\iradiusbagua+6.5\thickness) {\i};}
  \foreach \i [count=\xi from 5] in {?\ gèn\ 山,?\ k\v{a}n\ ?,?\ qián\ ?,?\ duì\ ?} {\node[rotate=45*(\xi+2)] at (45*\xi:\iradiusbagua+6.7\thickness) {\i};}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There's only one that I copied from another answer (next to `gèn`), but I'm not even sure that's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one you copied — 山 — is correct (it means "mountain" by the way). Since this is a known shape, you could search for it online and indeed, there's a Wikipedia article with all the characters included, about the [Bā Guà (八卦)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua) (it means "eight symbols").

I noticed you were missing the trigrams though, so here's the final version, along with the Yin Yang.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{STFangsong}

%Lengths definition
\newlength{\radiustai} %Radius of Taijitu symbol
\setlength{\radiustai}{1cm}
\newlength{\thickness} %Thickness of the trigram lines
\setlength{\thickness}{0.3\radiustai} %Change this factor to make the lines thicker or thinner
\newlength{\iradiusbagua} %Distance from center of Taijitu to the first line of Ba Gua.
\setlength{\iradiusbagua}{1.4\radiustai} %Change the factor to make the Ba Gua bigger or smaller. Factor 1 would make it tangent to the Taijitu.
\newlength{\smallradius} %Offset from the center for the trigram lines (see below for computation)
\newlength{\basedistance} %Base distance from lowest corner of Ba Gua trigram

%Colours definition
\definecolor{triborder}{gray}{0.7}
\definecolor{trifill}{gray}{0}
\definecolor{octafill}{gray}{0.9}
\definecolor{bckearth}{RGB}{240,230,140}
\definecolor{bckwater}{RGB}{30,144,255}
\definecolor{bckfire}{RGB}{220,20,60}
\definecolor{bckwood}{RGB}{50,205,50}
\definecolor{bckmetal}{RGB}{192,192,192}

\tikzset{
    nodeline/.style={midway, rotate=#1, minimum height=3.5mm, minimum width=2.5mm}, 
}

\newcommand\trigram[2]{%
\begin{scope}[rotate=#1]% around={#1:(0,0)}
\def\alenanno{w}
\clip (-1.1,3) -- (1.1,3) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\foreach \x [count=\xx starting from 0, evaluate=\xx as \y using (1.75+.5*\xx)] in #2{%
\ifx\x\alenanno
    \draw[line width=3mm] (-1.2,\y) -- (1.2,\y) node[nodeline=#1,fill=white] {};
\else
    \draw[line width=3mm] (-1.2,\y) -- (1.2,\y);
\fi
}
\end{scope}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  %External octagon: thanks to Mark Wibrow for the idea (from an answer on stackexchange).
\draw[line width=1,fill=octafill!80!black] (22.5:\iradiusbagua+8.5\thickness) 

\foreach \i in {45,90,...,315}{
    -- (\i+22.5:\iradiusbagua+8.5\thickness)
} -- cycle;
\draw[line width=2,fill=white] (22.5:\iradiusbagua+6.5\thickness) 

\foreach \i in {45,90,...,315}{
    -- (\i+22.5:\iradiusbagua+6.5\thickness)
} -- cycle;

\foreach \i in {22.5,67.5,...,337.5}{
    \draw[line width=1] (\i:\iradiusbagua+6.5\thickness) -- (\i:\iradiusbagua+8.5\thickness);
}
%
\foreach \trig/\blk/\pin/\wht [count=\xi, evaluate=\xi as \angle using int((45*\xi)-90)] in {%
    {w,w,w}/坤/kūn/地,
    {b,w,b}/離/lì/火,
    {w,b,b}/巽/xùn/風,
    {b,w,w}/震/zhèn/雷,
    {w,w,b}/艮/gèn/山,
    {w,b,w}/坎/kǎn/水,
    {b,b,b}/乾/qián/天,
    {b,b,w}/兌/duì/澤
    }{
    \trigram{\angle}{\trig}
    \ifnum\xi<5
        \node[rotate=45*(\xi-2)] at (45*\xi:\iradiusbagua+6.5\thickness) {\blk~\pin~\textcolor{white}{\wht}};
    \else
        \node[rotate=45*(\xi+2)] at (45*\xi:\iradiusbagua+6.7\thickness) {\blk~\pin~\textcolor{white}{\wht}};
    \fi
}
%
%\trigram{90}{b,w,b}
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill (90:5mm) circle (3pt);
\fill (90:1cm) arc (90:-90:5mm) arc (90:270:5mm) arc (-90:90:1cm);
\fill[white] (-90:5mm) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much indeed. I did have the trigrams: I only left them out to keep the MWE minimal (as the name suggests). However mine were a lot more complicated to do than your version. I will try to figure out how you did it and learn a lot about Latex indeed. I also thought about copying the characters from Wikipedia, but I thought they were only graphics and not actual fonts.

Comment: @Andyc Ah no worries about the characters. It was just in case you hadn't thought of it. :D If something isn't clear about how I did the trigrams, feel free to comment here.

Answer (score 1):

I am using XeLaTex to compile files including Chinese characters. Here is my beamer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{BiauKai}            % The main font you are using. 
\newCJKfontfamily\Kai{魏碑-繁}       % Set main font in your document.
\newCJKfontfamily\ChCal{行楷-繁}     % Set a new font so that you can 
\newCJKfontfamily\ChBlack{蘭亭黑-繁} % change the font in the document. 
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"          % Following set to break line automatically.
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt 
\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}

\begin{document}
     中文字測試
\end{document}
```

To do so, you will find the Chinese words appear.

By the way, I use TexShop on Mac OS. If you are going to compile with software on Windows, you can try to use font 「標楷體」 or 「新細明體」 first. For more fonts, you can visit [Wang Han Tsong Open Type Chinese Characters](http://lms.ltu.edu.tw/course_open.php?courseID=12961&f=open_doc&cid=684505) for more information about 「王漢宗Open Type字體」。

Comment: Also, you have to set your encoding to "UTF-8" to save your `.tex` file.

Comment: Please, add the call to `\documentclass` to your MWE...

Comment: Sorry, I lost it.

Comment: Thank you for your extended answer. However I already got it to type Chinese characters, although not as sophisticated as your example. What I'm missing is "what" to type, not "how" to type.  In other words I don't know what to type in my keyboard in order to make something like the things that are in the picture appear. That's because I don't know Chinese and therefore I can't read the characters and I can't enter them because I don't know what they are.

Comment: @Andyc The black or the white ones? In that case, the question should go to Chinese SE... If you want to type the black ones, then you can use the Pinyin on the image (the latin alphabet words), so for example, the bottom one is `kan`, so it's 坎.

Comment: @Alenanno Thank you. I thought it would be a question for Chinese SE. Feel free to move it there, if you deem necessary. Actually I would like to type both the black and the white ones. How do I enter pinyin in the .tex file and have it displayed as Chinese character?