# what is a better way to generate iching 64 hexagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, loops

If I have list for iching (bagua) trigrams as follows, what is the best way to generate 64 hexagrams as in shown in the image attached? I can use the use the binary code (e.g.{1,1,1}) for either color coding or draw the trigrams inspired from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325064/chinese-characters-of-ba-gua), or use the unicode [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472060/how-do-i-display-trigrams-from-the-unicode-miscellaneous-symbols-block). Is nested for-loop the right approach?  This is probably too much to ask.

```
{1,1,1}; 乾; 8;  ☰
{1,1,0}; 兌; 7;  ☱
{1,0,1}; 離; 6;  ☲
{1,0,0}; 震; 5;  ☳
{0,0,0}; 坤; 1;  ☷
{0,0,1}; 艮; 2;  ☶
{0,1,0}; 坎; 3;  ☵
{0,1,1}; 巽; 4;  ☴
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I apologize in advance that I am not able to use these characters. So I am assuming that you know how to use them (and what they mean). This answer just creates an array of Latin characters and Arabic numbers. You may thus want to redefine `\lstchar` to your needs.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
  \def\lstchar{{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
 "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", 
 "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
 "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
 "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", 
 "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
 "8", "9", "+", "-"}}
  \foreach \Z [evaluate=\Z as \Y using {int(\Z/8)},
  evaluate=\Z as \X using {int(mod(\Z,8))}] 
  in {0,1,2,...,63}
 {
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{mod(\Z,4)*255/3}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{mod(int(\Z/4),4)*255/3}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\z}{mod(int(\Z/16),4)*255/3}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\char}{\lstchar[\Z]}
 \definecolor{mycolor\Z}{RGB}{\z,\y,\x}
 \node[color=mycolor\Z,rotate={\Z*(360/64)-90},scale=1.5] at ({\Z*(360/64)}:7) {\char};
 \node[color=mycolor\Z,scale=1.5] at (\X-4+0.5,4-\Y-0.5) {\char};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, @marmot.  Your solution explains the placement elegantly.  I will explore how to stack the 8 trigrams to generate 64 hexagrams.

Comment: @TonyTan You can put `tabular`s  in the nodes. Just replace the node commands in my code by `\node[color=mycolor\Z,rotate={\Z*(360/64)-90},scale=1.5] at ({\Z*(360/64)}:7) 
 {\begin{tabular}{c}
 \char\\[-2mm]
 \char\\[-2mm]
 \char
\end{tabular}};
 \node[color=mycolor\Z,scale=1.5] at (\X-4+0.5,4-\Y-0.5) {
 \begin{tabular}{c}
 \char\\[-2mm]
 \char\\[-2mm]
 \char
\end{tabular}};`. Of course you can define more lists and thus get different characters.

Comment: If you want to display the hexagrams, one font that contains them is DejaVu Sans, and they have Unicode code points U+4DC0 to U+4DFF.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks! However, I hesitate to produce texts that I do not understand. But of course you could write an answer, I am curious how that looks.

Comment: @marmot Yes, good point. Especially since the symbols apparently have some kind of religious significance, of which I’m wholly ignorant.